# Does this variable follow a poisson distribution or a binomial distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

I dance an average of 2/7 nights during a week. D = Number of nights dancing in one month/4 weeks.

My first thought was Poisson, but am now unsure. Is it none of the above?

Comment: A binomial can be approximated to a poisson when $n$ is _large_ and $p$ is small. More specifically when $\frac{\lambda}{n} << 1$

Comment: Is it possible to dance more than once per night, or is each night a 'I dance yes or no' event?

Comment: No sorry i was not clear on that.
Assume it's "yes or no"

Answer (score 0):

It's binomial. D~bin(28, 2/7)

You want to see the number of successes D in n, 28, trials.

Comment: Can you explain why it is not poisson?
I see the rate and immediately think poisson.

Comment: If each night the probability of you dancing is 2/7 only then is it binomial. I read and just saw the 2/7 not the average part. Probabilities are binomial, averages/rates are poisson, except what @rightskewed said about λ/n

Comment: So that said, having just seen the "average" part, would you still say it is Binomial?

Comment: If you only dance on Friday and Saturday nights, however, the distribution won't be binomial. Or if dancing one night makes it less (or more) likely that you dance the next night, it won't be binomial. To be binomial, your probability of dancing on any one night must be independent of the night in question and of your dancing history.